# Restart IIS server from vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7

I have to Restart remote IIS server.

I am using web application.Is it possible?

I am using vb.net for as language.

Comment: Do you have administrator rights on the server?

Comment: @snoopcommands: Yes I have administrator rights on the server